# Shuffle an array randomly

Tags: algorithm, shuffle

Looking at the following algorithm for shuffling an array:

```
def shuffleSort(a):
  N = len(a)
  for i in range(N):
    j = random.randint(0, i)
    a[j], a[i] = a[i], a[j]
```

I believe it is called Fisher-Yates algorithm? I am looking for a rigorous mathematical proof of why this works. More specifically, let `(a1, ..., an)` be a permutation of `n`, I want to prove that `p((x1 = a1, ..., xn = an)) = 1/n!`.

Comment: After I wrote the proof below, I realized that we need the assumption that the elements are pairwise distinct for this statement to be true.

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical proof by induction.

The inductive hypothesis is, for k ∈ {0, 1, ..., n}, for every permutation π of {0, 1, ..., k − 1}, with probability at least 1/k!, the list values are a(π(0)), a(π(1)), ..., a(π(k−1)), a(k), a(k+1), ..., a(n−1), where a(i) denotes the original value at position i. For k = n, this proves that every permutation has probability at least 1/n!, which is almost what we want; the rest is by observing that these events are disjoint and have probability summing to one, hence equality must hold everywhere.

The base case k = 0 is obvious; there's only one permutation, and it exists in the original list with probability 1/0! = 1 by assumption.

For the inductive step, let φ = (π(k) k) ∘ π, in English, the permutation that modifies π by swapping k back to its original position. Invoking the inductive hypothesis, the probability that φ exists in the list after k−1 steps is at least 1/(k−1)!. With probability at least 1/k, the random number is π(k), which puts the desired permutation in the list with probability at least 1/(k−1)! × 1/k = 1/k!.